# How do I append String data to certain positions using python regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, replace

I am working on a simple python script; I have multiple Strings that look like this:

```
"Some show 14x01 - the one where they do thing 1"

"Some show 14x21 - the one where they do thing 2"

"Some show 10x11 - the one where they do thing 3"
```

I would like to replace and append characters so that they will instead be formatted like this:

```
"Some show S14E01 - the one where they do thing 1"

"Some show S14E21 - the one where they do thing 2"

"Some show S10E11 - the one where they do thing 3"
```

So ideally I am removing replacing the x with a capital E and appending the S to the front of the String segment.

I have figured out the regular expression to be used to identify the section to be altered,

```
r"\d{2}.\d{2}"
```

or

```
r"\d{2}\w\d{2}"
```

And have guessed this much:

```
for file in files:
    strFileName = str(file)
    strFileName = re.sub(r"\d{2}.\d{2}", ) # Unsure here
    strNew_name = 'Some show - ' + str(file) # Unsure here
    os.rename(file, strNew_name)
```

But I am at a loss as to how to proceed and finish this renaming process. Can someone help guide me to the answer or direct me to a SO question that has been asked that will help me to answer it please? Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend changing it to `\d{1,2}` incase theres something like `2x5` instead of `02x05`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can back-reference matched group in [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Some show 14x01 - the one where they do thing 1"
>>> re.sub(r"(\d{2}).(\d{2})", r"S\1E\2",s)
>>> 'Some show S14E01 - the one where they do thing 1'
```

Here `\1` refer to first matched group and `\2` refer to second matched group.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to send to the `sub` function:

`def replacement (match):
    return "S" + re.sub(r"[^\d]", "E", match.group(0))`

And then just send it to the `sub` function:

`strFileName = re.sub(r"\d{2}.\d{2}", replacement, strFileName)`